# R disable traceback after evaluating stop function

Tags: r, function, error-handling, traceback

I am using a function for error handling, which is used in another function. This looks like:

```
foo <- function() {
 fooo <- function () {
    stop('Hello World')
  }
  fooo()
}
```

Now upon calling `foo()`, R will provide a traceback option. However, if only `fooo()` is called (after running it as a stand alone function first) the `stop()` function will produce an error message without traceback. Ideally, I would prevent R from generating a traceback option and solely print the error message to the console. So.. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you running this in Rstudio?  Does it bother you that the "Show Traceback" option shows up?  Or is this something else?  From the standard command line you can't really tell the difference unless you run `traceback()`

Comment: Have you set `options(error=traceback)`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, options(error=NULL) seems to prevent traceback from showing up.

Comment: @BrodieG Yes this is in Rstudio, and it is not problematic for me in particular but the project I'm working on will be graded by people also using Rstudio. Traceback showing up instead of custom error handling is kinda.. unprofessional.